# handling cookie in get method, using google script

Tags: cookies, google-apps-script, get

1) In my browser I go to http://civil.poderjudicial.cl/CIVILPORWEB/ (in order to get a cookie).

2) then I go to http://civil.poderjudicial.cl/CIVILPORWEB/AtPublicoDAction.do?TIP_Consulta=2&RUT_Consulta=76559280&RUT_DvConsulta=1&irAccionAtPublico=Consulta

3) I got the information properly. Obviusly If I go directly to page listed in point 2 without the cookie gotten in point 1, I have no results.

I want automatize this sequence using google scripts this my the code:

```
var url="http://civil.poderjudicial.cl/CIVILPORWEB/"
var www=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var error_url=www.getResponseCode();
var res1=www.getAllHeaders();
var res1a=www.getAllHeaders();
var res2=www.getContentText("ISO-8859-1");
var res3=www.getHeaders();
var res4=UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url);
var cookies = res1['Set-Cookie'];
var cookies2= res1['Set-Cookie'];
var largo=cookies.length;
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
  cookies[i] = cookies[i].split( ';' )[0];
}

var opt ={  
"Host":" civil.poderjudicial.cl",
"method" : "get",
"headers": {
"Cookie": cookies.join('; ')
}

var url="http://civil.poderjudicial.cl/CIVILPORWEB/AtPublicoDAction.do?TIP_Consulta=2&RUT_Consulta=76559280&RUT_DvConsulta=1&irAccionAtPublico=Consulta";

  var www=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,opt);
  var error_url=www.getResponseCode();
  var res1=www.getAllHeaders();
  var res2=www.getContentText("ISO-8859-1");
  var res3=www.getHeaders();
  var res4=UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url);

  Logger.log(res2);
```

I got this error at the end for res2:

```
<IError 500: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean under name TribunalBox
```

This is part of the wireshark of my browser (in order to see the cookie) where it works properly as described at the beginning

```
GET /CIVILPORWEB/AtPublicoDAction.do?TIP_Consulta=2&TIP_Lengueta=tdTres&SeleccionL=0&RUT_Consulta=76559280&RUT_DvConsulta=1&NOM_Consulta=&APE_Paterno=&APE_Materno=&COD_Tribunal=0&irAccionAtPublico=Consulta HTTP/1.1
Host: civil.poderjudicial.cl
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8
Cookie: FLG_Version=0; FLG_Turno=0; CRR_IdFuncionario=1; COD_TipoCargo=2; COD_Tribunal=0; COD_Corte=98; COD_Usuario=autoconsulta1; GLS_Tribunal=Tribunal de Prueba; GLS_Comuna=Santiago; COD_Ambiente=3; COD_Aplicacion=2; GLS_Usuario=Juan Pe.a Perez; HORA_LOGIN=10:14; _ga=GA1.2.291752321.1446485874; JSESSIONID=0002mWutDJhkdM7PLnyCPAfnhN7+zwasportal11
```

For debugging

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url,opt);
  for(i in response) {
    Logger.log(i + ": " + response[i]);
 }
```

this is what I got:

```
[15-11-18 06:37:45:880 PST] UrlFetchApp.getRequest([http://civil.poderjudicial.cl/CIVILPORWEB/AtPublicoDAction.do?TIP_Consulta=2&RUT_Consulta=76559280&RUT_DvConsulta=1&irAccionAtPublico=Consulta, {headers={Cookie=JSESSIONID=0001cz9KmVWyNep8w3fv2h1MhIU+zwasportal11; FLG_Version=0; FLG_Turno=0; CRR_IdFuncionario=1; COD_TipoCargo=2; COD_Tribunal=0; COD_Corte=98; COD_Usuario=autoconsulta1; GLS_Tribunal=Tribunal de Prueba                                ; GLS_Comuna=Santiago; COD_Ambiente=3; COD_Aplicacion=2; GLS_Usuario=Juan Pe�a Perez; HORA_LOGIN=11:37}, method=get, Host= civil.poderjudicial.cl}]) [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:45:881 PST] Logger.log([headers:  [object Object], []]) [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:45:881 PST] Logger.log([method:  get, []]) [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:45:882 PST] Logger.log([payload:  , []]) [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:45:882 PST] Logger.log([followRedirects:  true, []]) [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:45:883 PST] Logger.log([validateHttpsCertificates:  true, []]) [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:45:883 PST] Logger.log([useIntranet:  false, []]) [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:45:884 PST] Logger.log([contentType:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded, []]) [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:45:884 PST] Logger.log([url:  http://civil.poderjudicial.cl/CIVILPORWEB/AtPublicoDAction.do?TIP_Consulta=2&RUT_Consulta=76559280&RUT_DvConsulta=1&irAccionAtPublico=Consulta, []]) [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:47:087 PST] UrlFetchApp.fetch([http://civil.poderjudicial.cl/CIVILPORWEB/AtPublicoDAction.do?TIP_Consulta=2&RUT_Consulta=76559280&RUT_DvConsulta=1&irAccionAtPublico=Consulta, {headers={Cookie=JSESSIONID=0001cz9KmVWyNep8w3fv2h1MhIU+zwasportal11; FLG_Version=0; FLG_Turno=0; CRR_IdFuncionario=1; COD_TipoCargo=2; COD_Tribunal=0; COD_Corte=98; COD_Usuario=autoconsulta1; GLS_Tribunal=Tribunal de Prueba                                ; GLS_Comuna=Santiago; COD_Ambiente=3; COD_Aplicacion=2; GLS_Usuario=Juan Pe�a Perez; HORA_LOGIN=11:37}, method=get, Host= civil.poderjudicial.cl}]) [1.202 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:47:087 PST] HTTPResponse.getResponseCode() [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:47:087 PST] HTTPResponse.getAllHeaders() [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:47:087 PST] HTTPResponse.getContentText([ISO-8859-1]) [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:47:087 PST] HTTPResponse.getHeaders() [0 segundos]
 [15-11-18 06:37:47:088 PST] UrlFetchApp.getRequest([http://civil.poderjudicial.cl/CIVILPORWEB/AtPublicoDAction.do?TIP_Consulta=2&RUT_Consulta=76559280&RUT_DvConsulta=1&irAccionAtPublico=Consulta]) [0 segundos]
```